# createQueryBuilder and setParameter with multiple parameters?

Tags: sql, symfony

I've been trying to create this SQL query and i keep on having an error with a 2nd parameter.

Maybe i am missing something here.

Here is my request :

```
$pointsTEF = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $pointsTEFs = $pointsTEF->createQueryBuilder('t')
                ->select('t.points')
                ->from('AppBundle:Tef', 't')
                ->where('t.epreuve = :epreuve')
                ->setParameter('epreuve',$valeur)
                ->andWhere('t.resultat = :resultat')
                ->setParameter('resultat',$valeurEpreuve)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

Is this the proper way of using setParameter(); ?

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0_.points AS points_0
>   FROM tef t0_ WHERE t0_.epreuve = ? AND t0_.resultat = ?' with params
>   ["CE", "B1"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are
>   1-based

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this

```
->setParameters(array('param1'=> $param1, 'param2' => $param2))
```

Documentation
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query

Comment: I think that it should be 'setParameters' instead of 'SetParamater'

Comment: Thank you for proposing this solution, for me sounds pretty logical to make an array(). I tried it right now and it gives me an error : 

Warning: Missing argument 2 for Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::setParameter(), called in AppBundle\Controller\DemandesController.php on line 250 and defined | Source code : http://pastebin.com/UEtDUwgq

Comment: You forgot the 's' ;) i'ts setParameter**s** and not setParamater

Comment: Thank you to you all ! I guess this end of semester is getting to me ! Sometimes you need to recheck the basic's to be sure you didn't misstype something. Ty again !

Comment: No problem, it happens to everyone  :)